# Laravel Ajax fetch data one to many relationship

Tags: ajax, laravel, database, relationship, one-to-many

I'm trying to fetch data from one to many relationship via Ajax Call.

My RestaurantOffer_table table:

```
id | restaurant_offer_id | tableName | fromNr | toNr 
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1                   | table1    | 1      | 4
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | 1                   | table2    | 5      | 10
```

Now, I have to fetch these data from this table.

Model **RestaurantOffer.php**

```
class RestaurantOffer extends Model
{
     protected $guarded = [];
     public function restaurant_offer_table()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RestaurantOffer_table::class);
    }
}
```

Model **RestaurantOffer_table.php**

```
class RestaurantOffer_table extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function restaurantoffer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(RestaurantOffer::class);
    }
}
```

Controller **RestaurantOffersController.php**

```
function fetchdata(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $data = RestaurantOffer::find($id);

    $output = array(
        'monthlySum'    =>  $data->monthlySum,
        'userProfitPercentage'    =>  $data->userProfitPercentage,
        ....................... 
    );

    if($request->ajax()) {
      echo json_encode($output);
  }  
       
}
```

In this controller, all my data from **RestaurantOffer** model are fetching as well, but how to fetch data also from **RestaurantOffer_table** model using the same function in controller.

**View Ajax function:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var image_index= $(this).attr('data-index');
$('#form_output').html('');
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('restaurantOffers.fetchdata')}}",
    method: 'get',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data)
    {                   
        $('#getMonthlySum').val(data.monthlySum);
        $('#userProfitPercentage').val(data.userProfitPercentage);
        $.........
         
        $('#contract_id').val(id);                
        $('#editContract').modal('show');
        $('#action').val('Speichern');
        $('.modal-title').text('Daten aktualisieren');
        $('#button_action').val('update');
        
    }
});
```

So, the question is, how to fetch data from **RestaurantOffer_table** for each row of RestaurantOffer via Ajax call. e.g

```
Restaurant 1 -> table1 | 1 | 4
                table2 | 5 | 10
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the Relation in model. Thats good. But did not used while fetching in controller.

You have mention the relation function in `with()` method while doing model query like  below

```
$data = RestaurantOffer::with('restaurant_offer_table')->where('id',$id)->first();
```

It will call eagerloading method in laravel.

But you can also use that relation method after the elequent query.

```
$data = RestaurantOffer::find($id);
$data->restaurant_offer_table; // like this.
```

But it is not eagerloaded and you can not use this function in js file so you have to eager load the data.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I changed from first() to get() and it is working well. In Ajax I used this code to display the result:
`$.each(data, function(index,value) {
  var str='';
  $.each(value.restaurant_offer_table, function(key,val) {
  str+='<p>'+val.tableName+': '+val.fromNr+' -> '+val.toNr+'</p>';
   });
  $('#tables').append(str);
});`

Comment: What if I would like to do "double eager loading"
Based on previous example: ```$data = RestaurantOffer::with('restaurant_offer_table')->with('restaurant_chairs')```

is it possible to take out for example count of chairs out of table, which is taken out of Restaurant offer?

Comment: `RestaurantOffer::with(['restaurant_offer_table' => function($query){
   $query->withCount('restaurant_chairs');
}])`

You can do somthing like this to get count of chair.